# In the MCU prime universe canon, what level of knowledge about the Snap does the general populace have?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe

In the prime MCU universe, the one in the same universe as the movies, what level of knowledge does the general population of Earth have about the snap/Blip.

For example, do they know that it was caused by an alien warlord using mystical artifacts from the dawn of time, and that the Avengers travelled to the past through the quantum realm to reverse it. Or were they told an inaccurate version of events to prevent panic?

Can their level of knowledge be demonstrated in universe, for example using dialog from the various MCU properties, or out of universe using statements/interviews from the writers, cast, promotional material, etc?

Comment: I can't really put this as an intelligent answer because I gotta watch it again, but I thought in SPiderman: No Way Home some of the kids mention the blip.

Comment: The in-universe population probably has a better idea of it than I do these days. I've completely lost the thread in MCU & I'm not watching it *all* again [again, again] to catch up. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's public knowledge that Thanos was responsible.

Cap covers it in his group meeting in *Endgame*

> You did the hardest part. You took the jump, you didn't know where you were gonna come down. And that's it. That's those little brave baby steps we gotta take. To try and become whole again, try and find purpose. I went in the ice in '45 right after I met the love of my life. Woke up 70 years later. You gotta move on. Gotta to move on. The world is in our hands. It's left to us guys, and we got to do something with it. Otherwise... **Thanos should have killed all of us.**

Whether the *mechanism* of the Snap/Blip is generally known is not really covered but it seems unlikely that the Avengers would have gone into great detail.

*Spider-man: Far From Home* from the school video tribute.

> Over five years ago, half of all life in the universe, including our own Midtown High, was wiped from existence.
>
> **But then, 8 months ago, a band of brave heroes brought us back.**

Plus they seem aware that Tony, Natasha, Cap & Vision are "dead".

Comment: For some reason, I had it in my head that  everyone in that meeting was a current or former super hero or Shield agent. Wasn't there a behind the scenes interview were they described one of the people there as the first openly gay super hero in the MCU?

Comment: No these were normal people. Joe Russo played the first openly gay *character* in the MCU and took a lot of flak for what was perceived as a "weak sauce" reference.

Comment: I can't remember where it was, but I think that he was described as being a super hero in a couple of interviews, as an easter egg to another franchise that the MCU hasn't covered. Not really a weak sauce reference, more a realistic one. That's how people do things in real life.